# Can I optimize my LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create my very first database queries using LINQ. For practice I'm using the [Adventure Works 2014](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587) database from Microsoft.

[DB Diagram](https://akela.mendelu.cz/~jprich/vyuka/db2/AdventureWorks2008_db_diagram.pdf).

One of my first goals is to create static method for DataService returning a list of all products for given vendor's name. It looks like my method returns the correct data, but I think it is very poorly optimized. Can I improve it somehow?

```
public static List<Product> GetProductsByVendorName(string vendorName)
{
    AdventureWorksDatabaseClassDataContext dc = new AdventureWorksDatabaseClassDataContext();
    int vendorID = dc.Vendors.Where(vendor => vendor.Name == vendorName).Select(vendor => vendor.BusinessEntityID).First();

    IEnumerable <ProductVendor> productsVendor = dc.ProductVendors;
    IEnumerable<int> selectedProductsID = from ProductVendor productVendor in productsVendor
                                          where productVendor.BusinessEntityID == vendorID
                                          select productVendor.ProductID;

    IEnumerable<Product> products = dc.Products;
    IEnumerable<Product> selectedProducts = from Product p in products
                                            where selectedProductsID.Contains(p.ProductID)
                                            select p;

    return selectedProducts.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're writing out a join in code. Write it in a query instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because none specific problem with this code was specified. Consider to ask refactoring questions at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, yes, use a single query instead of three different ones.

Comment: I recommend you look into using Navigation properties in a single query.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm not allowed to use other frameworks or tools than LINQ to SQL (academic requirements).

Comment: avoid static. __

Comment: "not allowed to use other ... than LINQ to SQL" - go to another school or college. This is terribly outdated stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use joins on database side to avoid transferring data over network and loading entities into memory:

```
from v in dc.Vendors
join pv in dc.ProductVendors on v.BusinessEntityID equals v.BusinessEntityID
join p in dc.Products on p.ProductID equals pv.ProductID
where v.Name == vendorName
select p
```

Note that if you have proper setup of navigation properties, then this query can look like

```
dc.Vendors.Where(v => v.Name == vendorName)
  .SelectMany(v => v.ProductVendors.Select(pv => pv.Product))
```